# Socket.io sending message to specific socket.id not working?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have this app in socket.io using node.js server and I want to update the points for every one connected in the app. I keep a list of connected users by socket.id and secret in the clients array.
And I tried like this but the points won't update. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
function updatePoints(){
    points = [];
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", function(error, rows) {
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                points.push({"secret" : rows[i].secret, "points" : rows[i].pontos});
            }
            for (var l = 0; l < points.length; l++) {
                for (var p = 0; p < clients.length; p++) {
                    if(points[l].secret == clients[p].secret){
                        var socketID = clients[p].socket;
                        var pontos = points[l].points;
                        io.sockets.connected[socketID].emit('update points', pontos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Socket.io version: 1.3.7

Answer (score 1):

How about make a client object theb assigning a socket and a point property then push it in a the clients array?

```
socketServer.on('connection', function(socket){
     //make your query here
     ...
     //make a client object
     var client = {point: row.point, socket: socket};
     clients[row.secret] = client;
});
```

then you can retrieve the client by:

```
//query...
....
clients[row.secret].socket.emit('something', function);
```

edit:

if you want to broadcast to connected clients then you can:

```
socketServer.emit('something', function);
```

if you want to broad to everyone except the one who emitted the broadcast. then you can:

```
clients[row.secret].broadcast.emit('something', function;
```

Comment: You can use 4 spaces, or the `{}` button for code blocks.

Comment: But the points won't be updated at the connection event, but whenever the user spends points or earns it. Then I'll just update the points for everyone and send the value so they can see it changing real time in browser

Comment: @Matt sorry, im on mobile. its hard to type in this stuff.  wait ill edit my answer

Comment: @John Pangilinan I figured out my problem. I use jquery to load a page inside another, and since those 2 pages have different content I use io.connect() on each one, which makes me connect from 2 different sockets.  But the message is sent to the main page one, is there a way I can connect from only 1 socket for both pages?

Comment: Your question is unclear. are you trying to send a message or trying to connect? i didnt get the "connect from 1 socket" part, do you want to use one socket?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the

```
io.sockets.connected[socketID].emit('update points', pontos);
```

with this

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketID).emit('update points', pontos);
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: socket is not defined`

Somehow the client is not receiving the message